# Adding a progress bar to Jwrapper installation splash screen and specifying positioning of application shortcut in Windows Start Menu

Tags: java, progress-bar, startmenu

I am currently working with a config.xml file that JWrapper uses directly, and I have 2 problems I am trying to solve. The first thing I want to do is add a loading animation(as a progress bar) at the bottom of the SplashScreen while my JWrapper application is installing. This progress bar appears when Uninstalling the app, but does not when I try to install it. I believe there is a built in progress bar for JWrapper but I do not know how to enable it.

The second thing I am trying to do is put the shortcut to my app in the Start Menu in a specific directory that is different then the BundleName i.e (Company Name folder). As it currently is, it is being placed in the MyApp Directory. here is part of my xml file code :

```
<JWrapper>

<!-- The name of the app bundle -->

<BundleName>MyApp</BundleName>

<!-- The specification for one app within the bundle -->
<App>
    <Name>MyAppName</Name>
    <LogoPNG>resources/iS-icon-128x128.png</LogoPNG>
    <MainClass>*hidden*(</MainClass>
    <Param>one</Param>
</App>


<SupportedLanguages>en</SupportedLanguages>

<!-- App is a per-user app, it won't elevate and install for all users and 
    the shared config folder will be per-user -->
<InstallType>CurrentUser</InstallType>

<!-- Splash and Logo -->
<SplashPNG>resources/iS-installer.png</SplashPNG>
<BundleLogoPNG>resources/iS-icon-128x128.png</BundleLogoPNG>


</JWrapper>
```

This is not everything inside the file. I did not find JWrapper documentation that helps with what I wish to do. Does anyone know how I can implement these features?